# PHP create option list from delimited string without duplicating values

Tags: php

I have a string with values (which are suburbs) like so:

```
$suburbs = "Mawson, Elizabeth, Burnside, Elizbeth, Mawson";
```

There COULD be double ups in the suburbs that the string contains. I can't change this fact.

What I am trying to do is create an option list for a drop down menu that a user will use. I do not want to display the same suburb twice( or more for that matter).

What I have so far:

```
$suburbs = "Mawson, Elizabeth, Burnside, Elizbeth, Mawson";
//Explode the suburbs string delimited by a comma
$boom = explode(',', $suburbs);

foreach($boom as $b)
{
$suburbOptionList .= '<option value='.$b.'>'.$b.'</option>';
}
?>
<select> <?php
echo $suburbOptionList;
?>
</select>
```

I know that this will simply display all of the options but I really don't know how to display each suburb only once. Ive tried a few foreach,and if combinations but they look ugly and work just as bad.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Cheers in advance!

Comment: Just a side note: I would use a comma with a space `, ` as the delimiter. Since technically you have one `Mawson` and one ` Mawson`, which are not the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass $boom through [array_unique()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) and you'll be fine.

```
$bada_boom = array_unique($boom);
```

P.S.: This will not help if you have typos or variations in duplicates. (Elizbeth != Elizabeth).
In that case you will need to get creative.

Also, hw (in comments) made a good point about trimming whitespaces. If the suburbs come from an untrusted source and are improperly formatted, you may need to normalize them. This means trimming whitespaces and normalizing capitals:

```
$boom = array_walk($boom, 'trim');
$boom = array_walk($boom, 'strtolower');
$bada_boom = array_unique($boom);
```

Comment: In addition to above, you also need to trim values just in case there are spaces around the word, as in your case. You can use `$boom = array_walk($boom, 'trim')` before calling `array_unique`.