# PHP How to make a dropdown with database data

Tags: php, html-select, dropdown

So I have this `database` and it has column called `selectedDates`. In that column there is a row with the values

```
2018-08-22
2018-08-15
2018-08-20
```

Keep in mind this is 3 sets of dates, but in one row. How do I make a select tag/dropdown with these three values. Is this possible to do? If more information is needed, let me know and I will edit.

Down below is my code for having it do a dropdown of options within one column, but different rows. Such as

```
 Column 1
Row 1 -  Dog
Row 2 - Cat
Row 3 - Mouse
```

I need it to be like

```
Column 1 
Row 1 - Dog,Cat,Mouse
```

and then have the dropdown options as dog cat mouse

example code below of column 1, 3 different rows

```
 <?php
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'races');

if($con->connect_errno) {
// error reporting here
}

$result = $con->query("SHOW TABLES");

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo '<select id="myTable" onchange="myFunction()">';
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    echo '<option value="Test" name="SelectedDate">' . $row[0] . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
} ?>
```

edit for replying to comment 
Example database

```
Id | Info | SelectedDates 
1    hi    2018-18,2018-19 
2    hi    2018-20,2018-21
```

In the code you provided, in my example it would only create a dropdown with id 1, but if I had another row like id 2, can i change `$row[0]` to `$row[1]` to have my dropdown display the 2nd row of selected dates?

Comment: We would love to see your coding attempt.  This is a basic task with a few ways to satisfy.  What is the delimiter?  Think of code as cars.  StackOverflow volunteers are "mechanics" not "manufacturers".  Please show us your failed coding attempt.

Comment: This is one column in one row, I know how to do a dropdown if it were in different rows in the same column, but I need it to be the same row, same column. I separated them with a \n, but I can use a , if its easier to use in code. I will edit question with code attempt

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16985603/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/36832490/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/37289197/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/31911375/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/49289855/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want to check for a connection without explicitly checking the `connect_errno` property, you can simply check for a `false` $con value.
- You should nominate the exact columns that you are going to access from your resultset.  If you are only targeting the one row, only query for that one.
- As a more brief syntax, you can drop `> 0` and check for a non-falsey `$result->num_rows` value.
- If you want to identify resultset columns by index, you can use `$result->fetch_row()` (again shorter syntax)
- `myTable` is an inappropriate id value for your `<select>` tag -- because it is not a "table".  I cannot suggest a better one because I don't know what your greater form structure is.
- `<option>` tags don't take a `name` attribute, that goes in the parent `<select>` tag.
- Setting a static `value` attribute value of `Test` will result in all options submitting the same value: `Test` (obviously that doesn't make sense).  In fact, unless you need to reformatted/modify the date value, don't write a `value` attribute at all; just rely on the option's text to contain the value.

Untested Suggestion: (assuming you are processing just one row of data)

```
if (!$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'races')) {
    // connection error
} elseif (!$result = $con->query("SELECT selectedDates FROM `your_table` WHERE id = " . (int)$id)) {
    // query syntax error
} elseif (!$row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    // possible logic error, no row found
} else {
    echo '<select id="myTable" name="SelectedDate" onchange="myFunction()">';
    foreach (explode(",", $row[0]) as $date) {
        echo "<option>$date</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
```

Comment: This works, but if it's from a different row, can I just change $row[0] accordingly?

Comment: Do you mean you have several rows that have comma-separated values?  Do you want all of the dates from all rows as `<option>`s in a single `<select>`? or do you mean you want to create a new `<select>` for each row of the resultset?

Comment: `[0]` of `$row[0]` is the column identifier.  If you used associative keys, the comma-separated values would be accessed via `$row['selectedDates']`.

Comment: If you want all `selectedDates` data from multiple rows, then I would recommend grouping in the query itself (joining with commas).  If you want separate `<select>`s, then you replace the second `elseif` with `else` and write a `while($row = $result->fetch_row()){` loop inside of that.

Comment: If I created a new row with comma-separated values, can I change my dropdown to show that rows values instead of the first one.

Comment: That is more to do with query logic.  You will want to write a `WHERE` clause in your query to isolate the "latest" using whatever logic is available in the table.  If `WHERE` isn't suitable, you _could_ do `ORDER BY [some_column] DESC LIMIT 1` to isolate the "last" row.  I can't be too concrete about my advice without more/better info.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. Basically I just had to do 'WHERE Id = 17' and that was all

Answer (score 0):

You say you must have all the dates in the same column, why?

Isn't this a database misconception? If you need multiple row for one value, you should have a table with "id | selectedDate" so that the issue you are speaking about does not happen.

If you must continue like this, you should try to look at this: https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/function.explode.php

Hope it helps.

Comment: I need all the dates in one row, not column. I wish i can add images to show what my database looks like. I have all the rows set up with an Id as my auto int, primary key. 
I can't use explode since there is no array that I am using.

Comment: We don't need an image of your db, you can go to phpmyadmin and export the structure and row -- in fact that is preferred from a volunteer's perspective because then the details are 100% accurate and we can copy-paste.  `explode()` doesn't require an array, it creates one.